# Standard practice for a servlet to support two output formats

Tags: java, servlets

Up until now; our servlet only used to support `application/json` as the output format. In fact; we just returned the output as `application/json`; with no regards to what the user requested :(

Going forward; we are going to support multiple output formats: json/xml etc. 
I was wondering; what is the industry practice to enable this? Do we just read the `getContentType()` from the `HttpServletRequest` and return the appropriate data format?

Comment: You are looking for the [`Accept` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Most web services I've used take a `GET` parameter example : `?format=json` or `?format=xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getContentType()` returns the `Content-Type` header value for the request. This specifies the content of the body of the HTTP request. Not the content type it is expecting as a response.

An HTTP request can have the [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header set

> to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response. Accept headers can be used to indicate that the request is specifically limited to a small set of desired types, as in the case of a request for an in-line image.

Used as

```
Accept: text/plain 
// or application/xml or a comma separated list for multiple types  (which you would have to parse)
```

From the `HttpServletRequest`, you can retrieve it as

```
String responseContentType = request.getHeader("Accept");
```

Javadoc for `HttpServletRequest#getHeader(String)` is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29).

Obviously, if your client is a browser, it's a little hard to change the header.